# Find in terms of $p$, $\tan(-\alpha)$, $\tan(\pi - \alpha)$ and $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)$.

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $\tan$ $\alpha = p$, where $\alpha$ is acute, find in terms of $p$, $\tan(-\alpha)$, $\tan(\pi - \alpha)$ and $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the following facts:

- $\tan(\alpha) = \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)}$
- $\sin(-\alpha) = -\sin(\alpha)$
- $\cos(-\alpha) = \cos(\alpha)$
- $\sin(\pi-\alpha) = \sin(\alpha)$
- $\cos(\pi-\alpha) = -\cos(\alpha)$
- $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha) = \cos(\alpha)$
- $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha) = \sin(\alpha)$.

Comment: your answer is useful, but how do i relate it with $p$?

Comment: Well you know that $p = \tan(\alpha)$, and that equals $\sin(\alpha)/\cos(\alpha)$. For example, $\tan(-\alpha) = \sin(-\alpha)/\cos(-\alpha)$, can you see the rest?

Answer (score 2):

- $\tan(-\alpha)=-\tan(\alpha)$ (Prove it!). Thus, $\tan(-\alpha)=-p$.
- $\tan(\pi-\alpha)=-\tan(\alpha)$ (Prove it!). Thus, $\tan(\pi-\alpha)=-p$.
- $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)=\cot(\alpha)$ (Prove it!). Thus, $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)=p^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the identity
$$\tan(\theta+\phi)\equiv \frac{\tan(\theta)+\tan(\phi)}{1-\tan(\theta)\tan(\phi)}.$$

Substitute the appropriate values of $\theta$ and $\phi$ into the above identity.

For the first part, note that $\tan(-\theta)\equiv -\tan(\theta)$ (since $\tan$ is an **odd** function).

Answer (score -1):

$$\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2+\alpha} = - \sin \alpha \\
\sin\dfrac{\pi}{2+\alpha} = \cos \alpha$$